# My laptops one sound is not working.Only right sound works.How to fix it?

Tags: sound, soundcard

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F6co.png)

The left sound works perfectly fine in windows.But in Ubuntu 16.04 only right sound works.How to fix this problem. Attachment is screenshot from terminal alsamixer version 1.1.0

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you [edit] your question and provide more info on the sound hardware you're using? Add the output to `lshw` to your question